# How to add a top bar to the view?

Tags: ios, ios7

I am in the designing of ios view. I would like to add a top bar.

I know I can use navigation bar, but I am not sure if this is the prefered way. I think I don't need home button.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the navigationItem in the xib file,and setting its property,but not using NavigationController.